# Time series in R: How do I calculate percent change from a fixed year for multiple time series variables in R?

Tags: r, matrix, time-series, percentage

For multiple time series variables, how do I  calculate the percent change over time relative to a fixed year?

```
structure(list(haiarYear = 2009:2012, 
               anyInf = c(25914L, 23601L, 22713L, 22654L), 
               haiarPatDays = c(10402161L, 10289079L, 10212208L, 10033090L), 
               rate = c(2.49121312388839, 
                        2.29379131018432, 
                        2.22410276014746, 
                        2.25792851454537)), 
               .Names = c("haiarYear", "anyInf", "haiarPatDays", "rate"), 
               row.names = c(NA, -4L), 
               class = "data.frame")
tsInfPatDays <- ts(tInfPatDays[,-1], start=2009)
options(digits=2)
```

Produces a time-series structure that looks like this:

```
Time Series:
Start = 2009 
End = 2012 
Frequency = 1 
     anyInf haiarPatDays rate
2009  25914     10402161 2.49
2010  23601     10289079 2.29
2011  22713     10212208 2.22
2012  22654     10033090 2.26
```

I want to calculate the percent change relative to 2009 for each of the variables: `anyInf`, `haiarPatDays` and `rate`.

For one variable, I can calculate percent change as:

```
transform(tsInfPatDays, since2009 = (rate-rate[1])/rate[1]*100)
```

Yielding:

```
anyInf haiarPatDays rate since2009
 25914     10402161 2.49      0.00
 23601     10289079 2.29     -7.92
 22713     10212208 2.22    -10.72
 22654     10033090 2.26     -9.36
```

The following calculates percent change relative to the previous year and operates on each variable:

```
100*(tsInfPatDays/lag(tsInfPatDays, -1)-1)
```

Giving:

```
Time Series:
Start = 2010 
End = 2012 
Frequency = 1 
     tsInfPatDays.anyInf tsInfPatDays.haiarPatDays tsInfPatDays.rate
2010               -8.93                    -1.087             -7.92
2011               -3.76                    -0.747             -3.04
2012               -0.26                    -1.754              1.52
```

Using this as a model, I expected to be able to perform the calculation by I needed by indexing the 2009 reference data `tsInfPatDays[1,]`

```
  anyInf haiarPatDays         rate 
2.59e+04     1.04e+07     2.49e+00
```

Then:

```
(tsInfPatDays-tsInfPatDays[1,])/tsInfPatDays[1,]*100
```

The first row appears to be calculated properly, however subsequent rows are clearly wrong.

I have seen a transposed matrix approach for row subtraction. Although not a percentage, as a proof of concept, I tried subtracting the values of the reference row from the time series rows. I got the following error:

```
t(tsInfPatDays-t(tsInfPatDays[1,]))

Error in `-.default`(tsInfPatDays, t(tsInfPatDays[1, ])) : 
  non-conformable arrays
```

I get the same error if I try to extract the data before using the transposed matrix approach:

```
 t(tsInfPatDays-t(drop(coredata(tsInfPatDays[1,]))))

 Error in `-.default`(tsInfPatDays, t(drop(coredata(tsInfPatDays[1, ])))) : 
 non-conformable arrays
```

Comment: check out the `data.table` package, then have a look at the `roll` and `mult` arguments in `?data.table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over columns:

```
 ts(sapply(tsInfPatDays,function(x)(x-x[1])/x[1]*100), start= 2009)
Time Series:
Start = 2009 
End = 2012 
Frequency = 1 
         anyInf haiarPatDays       rate
2009   0.000000     0.000000   0.000000
2010  -8.925677    -1.087101  -7.924726
2011 -12.352396    -1.826092 -10.722100
2012 -12.580073    -3.548022  -9.364298
```

Comment: While your solution addresses my question, I guess I was hoping to learn about manipulating ts structures and why they work like matrices in some respects and not others. Since diff() and lag() operate relative to other points in time, I thought it should be easy to apply a function to the ts structure with an absolute point-in-time reference.

Comment: @penguinv22 Personaly I don't use a lot `ts` and exactly for this "odd/no uniform" behavior. I prefer to use `xts` package.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to calculate it:

## tfplot package

```
#check if exist the packages installed
if(!require('tfplot')) {
install.packages('tfplot')
library('tfplot')
}

#create a time series randomly 
z <- ts(matrix(100 + rnorm(200),100,2), start=c(1990,1), frequency=12)
z[z == 0] <- 1 

#Convert level data to year over year percent change.
zyypc <- ytoypc(z)

zpc <- percentChange(z)

plot(zpc)
print(zpc)
```

You can learn more at this link: [tfplot documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tfplot/tfplot.pdf)

## dse package

There is another package very useful too (using the same data bellow):

```
if(!require('dse')) {
install.packages('dse')
library('dse')
}

y <- percentChange(z)
```

You can learn more at this link: [dse documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tfplot/tfplot.pdf)